# Using internal speakers for skype calls with headset plugged in

Tags: sound, skype

Is there any way I could make sound come through my system's internal speakers instead of headphones, with headphones inserted as I have to speak through them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to choose either one of them , since I assume you only have one 'Jack' port so either it can be headphones or speakers!